# advance template Yii2 - redirect to frontend/web using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, yii, yii2

Now I am using advance template Yii2. And using htaccess to redirect http:://mydomain.com to frontend/web folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|ember)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^ember/(.*)$ web/ember/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|ember)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    #RewriteRule (.*) frontend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but when I go to any url ie : http://mydomain.com/abc . the site always point to home page.. Even url not invailable..

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just copy the contents of the frontend/web folder into your webroot folder?

Answer (score 3):

This .htaccess file works for me, you have to put this .htaccess file under 
**yii2advance/frontend/** root directory,

so when you access **yii2advance.com/frontend/** it'll rewrite as **yii2advance.com/frontend/web**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)      frontend/web/index.php/$1   [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: What are QSA, L and NC? And ... does this allow pretty url?

Answer (score 1):

please create .htaccess in frontend/web with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|ember)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ember/(.*)$ web/ember/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|ember)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule (.*) frontend/web/$1 [L]
```