# Yii2 | Redirect to backend/frontend with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 advanced template on `localhost` and I want to redirect the user to `backend/web` when the url is `localhost/site/admin` and redirect to `frontend/web` when the url is `localhost/site` using `.htaccess` file.

I enabled `apache rewrite` and I have tried these solutions 
[advance template Yii2 - redirect to frontend/web using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605952/advance-template-yii2-redirect-to-frontend-web-using-htaccess)
[Yii2 .htaccess redirect to backend part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912419/yii2-htaccess-redirect-to-backend-part)
[Redirecting to backend via htaccess Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360584/redirecting-to-backend-via-htaccess-yii2)

but in all cases I get `404 Error` when the url is `localhost/site/admin`

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /site/admin was not found on this server.

and when the url is `localhost/site` the content of the root directory of my site is displayed to me.

Now my `.htaccess` in the root of project is :

```bsh
# prevent directory listings
    Options -Indexes
    IndexIgnore */*

    # follow symbolic links
    Options FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

and in `backend/web` and `frontend/web` is:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: I am not sure about it, but I believe `RewriteRule ^(.+)admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]` should work. I think you are matching for `localhost/admin` with the above rule. Please, let me know how it goes.

Comment: create 2 virtual hosts and make your life easier by ruling out the `.htaccess` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955171/yii2-separate-front-and-backend-in-advanced-app-doesnt-work-on-xampp/48956244#48956244)

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Lastly, I noticed that although I had ‍`mod_rewrite` enabled through the terminal, there was no change in the configuration file and I made the changes manually.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for your suggestion but the site must be on a shared host and I don't have access to build virtual hosts

Comment: if you are on a live server you can either use the `symlink` or the front and backend or follow this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-shared-hosting.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I had enabled `mod_rewrite` through the terminal via the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

But it was not enabled and I manually activated it from ‍`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

use it without `site`

```
localhost/admin
```